# Can't understand how to call a method

Tags: java, methods

Conditions of a task:

- The main method should stop reading lines from the keyboard if an invalid string was entered (not "cartoon", not "thriller" or not "soapOpera");
- For each string entered (including invalid strings), the MovieFactory.getMovie() method must be called;

Another conditions is not so important for my problem.

My problem is I can't understand how to call a MovieFactory.getMovie() for an invalid strings.
IMPORTANT! Strings of "default" is my my attempt to resolve the condition, but it doesn't work.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Movie movie = null;
    String key;
    while (true)
    {
        key = reader.readLine();
        boolean b = key.equals("soapOpera") || key.equals("cartoon") || key.equals("thriller");
        if (!b) break;

        switch (key)
        {
            case "soapOpera":
                movie = MovieFactory.getMovie("soapOpera");
                System.out.println(movie.getClass().getSimpleName());
                break;
            case "cartoon":
                movie = MovieFactory.getMovie("cartoon");
                System.out.println(movie.getClass().getSimpleName());
                break;
            case "thriller":
                movie = MovieFactory.getMovie("thriller");
                System.out.println(movie.getClass().getSimpleName());
                break;
            default:
                movie = MovieFactory.getMovie(key);
                System.out.println(movie.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    }
}

static class MovieFactory
{
    static Movie getMovie(String key)
    {
        Movie movie = null;

        if ("soapOpera".equals(key))
        {
            movie = new SoapOpera();
        }
        else if ("cartoon".equals(key))
        {
            movie = new Cartoon();
        }
        else if ("thriller".equals(key))
        {
            movie = new Thriller();
        }
        return movie;
    }
}

static abstract class Movie
{

}

static class SoapOpera extends Movie
{

}

static class Cartoon extends Movie
{

}

static class Thriller extends Movie
{

}
```

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Your main method does not need the switch block -- get  rid of it. Instead, pass whatever key string is obtained into the `MovieFactory.getMovie(...)` method and test what is returned. If it returns `null` then the String entered is invalid.

Comment: Agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels.. Keep this statement at the end of while loop "if (!b) break;"

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your main method a lot:

- use the stop condition in the while loop instead of `if` with `break`
- don't do the same thing in the `switch` over and over again
- use a `List<String>` to check for valid keys
- minimize the visibility of your variables but extend it where necessary

```java
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
List<String> validKeys = List.of("soapOpera", "cartoon", "thriller");
boolean validKey = true;

while (validKey) {
    String key = reader.readLine();
    validKey = validKeys.contains(key);

    Movie movie = MovieFactory.getMovie(key);
    System.out.println(movie.getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

UPDATE: with a modern version of Java (would recommend at least 17) you can also simplify your method `getMovie` a lot:

```java
static Movie getMovie(String key) {
    return switch(key) {
        case "soapOpera" -> new SoapOpera();
        case "cartoon" -> new Cartoon();
        case "thriller" -> new Thriller();
        default -> new Unknown();
    };
}
```

But you have to add a new class for your case where the key is unknown:

```java
static class Unknown extends Movie{}
```

Comment: Who needs while loops even `reader.lines().takeWhile(validKeys::contains).map(MovieFactory::getMovie).forEach(it -> System.out.println(it.getClass().getSimpleName()));` :)

Comment: @zapl true. I just didn't want to show a programming beginner code that is hard to understand, but easily to spot as copied from SO ;-)